# Displaying number of times a character is in a string

Tags: java

I need to print the amount of times an input character appears in the string. It runs and works for all tests, however when a character appears only 1 time it prints "1 times" instead of "1 time" like expected, and i am unsure of how to add this into my code. It has to be when count is equal to 1 the outprint changes from times to time. I am lost.

```
 for( i = 0; i < input.length(); i ++){
     if (input.charAt(i) == letter)
     {
     count = count + 1;
     }
  }
  System.out.println("The letter '" + letter + "' appears "  + count + " times in the string " + "\"" + input + ".\"");
```

Expected to

Comment: You know how the `if` works right? You could just have a `suffix` that starts blank and if `count > 1` set `suffix = "s"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a condition for the same instead of printing the static string "times" as below:

```
for( i = 0; i < input.length(); i ++){
     if (input.charAt(i) == letter)
     {
     count = count + 1;
     }
  }
String str = (count==1)?"time":"times";
  System.out.println("The letter '" + letter + "' appears "  + count + str + " in the string " + "\"" + input + ".\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this

```
String plural =  (count == 1) ? "" : "s";
System.out.println("The letter '" + letter + "' appears "  + count + " time" + plural + "in the string " + "\"" + input + ".\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

### I would use an if statement to determine how many times this specific letter appears in your string. Also, since first character is charAt(0), the last character should be charAt(s.length()-1);.

```
for( i = 0; i < (input.length()-1); i ++){
    if (input.charAt(i) == letter) 
        count = count + 1;    
} //end of your for loop
if (count == 1){
    System.out.println("The letter '" + letter + 
    "' appears "  + count + " time in the string " + "\"" + input + ".\"");
 }
 else{
    System.out.println("The letter '" + letter + "' appears "  + count + " times in the string " + "\"" + input + ".\"");
 }
```